# Placing variables. Should it be reversed?

Tags: logic

I'm reading the book 'Logic, A Very Short Introduction' and came across the following text.

> This is one version of an argument for the existence of God, often
> called the Cosmological Argument. One might object to the
> argument in various ways. But at its heart, there is an enormous
> logical fallacy. The sentence ‘Everything has a cause’ is ambiguous.
> It can mean that everything that happens has some cause or
> other—that is, for every x, there is a y, such that x is caused by y;
> or it can mean that there is something which is the cause of
> everything—that is, there is some y such that for every x, x is
> caused by y. Suppose we think of the relevant domain of objects
> as causes and effects, and write ‘x is caused by y’ as xCy. Then
> we can write these two meanings as, respectively

It said it results in the following:

1. $∀x$ $∃y$ $xCy$
2. $∃y$ $∀x$ $xCy$

But should the second one not be reversed like: $yCx$, because $y$ causes $x$?

My knowledge about logic is very limiting and I'm trying to understand the basics of it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You may want to post this to philosophy.stackexchange too.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note what the text says:

"and write ‘x is caused by y’ as xCy."

So the causing agent is on the *right*, and the resulting effect is on the *left*.

That means that the last bit of your second equation, "xCy" means "x is caused by y", which is the same as "y causes x".

I honestly think that this was a simple problem of misreading: we're used to sentences having the structure 'subject-verb-object' as in 'injury causes pain', but in this case "C" is set up in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! `That means that the last bit of your second equation, "xCy" means "x is caused by y", which is the same as "y causes x".` did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

> My knowledge about logic is very limiting and I'm trying to understand the basics of it.

One important principles is *"ex falso quodlibed"*, and many have problems to graps that. **Based on something wrong all else is true.** Example: If the moon is a green cheese then 'Tom/Peter/Joe/*yourchoice*' is a womens first name. -- True! simply because the moon is not a green cheese. Got it?!
To apply this basic principle to other statements is now your task.